# Move cursor and display it in another place

Tags: javascript, cursor, cursor-position, onmousemove

I am learning JavaScript. And I have this task - to draw two rectangles, in one of them, I should move the cursor, and it should appear in the second rectangle. It is not that hard to track the cursor, bu I have no idea how to display it somewhere else. Do I need to create separate canvas? How to display cursor image?
I would be very grateful for any tips!

Here is a simple code that I have for now:

```
<html>   
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" ></canvas>
    <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(20, 20, 300, 200);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.rect(350, 20, 300, 200);
    ctx.stroke();

    var cursorX;
    var cursorY;
    document.onmousemove = function(e){
        cursorX = e.pageX;
        cursorY = e.pageY;
    }
    </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an IMG with a cursor in it. Then, when you are moussing over one rectangle, use the img's (or containing DIV's) css to display it over the second rectangle correctly. It is similar to how you might display a tooltip

```
function (event) {
  var x = event.pageX;
  var y = event.pageY;
    var mouseImg = document.getElementById('mouseImg');
    if (mouseImg ) {
      $(mouseImg ).css('left',(x + rectangleOffset.x) + 'px');
      $(mouseImg ).css('top',y + rectangleOffset.y + 'px');
      $(mouseImg ).show();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you give me a hint, where to put img declaration?

Comment: @Cassie it really doesn't matter where you put the img declaration, as long as you do (css): `position: fixed;` and then hide it on load

Comment: @Cassie you're welcome. I'm just thinking also that you might want to use css `position: relative` instead of fixed. that way if you scroll the img should/will scroll with the box. I was just doing tooltips in a section of my document that has position: fixed, and this is why this worked for me. GL!

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day :)

Comment: I was wrong again. The answer is position: absolute